# Mongo authentication fail or invalid connection string

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Using `"mongoose": "^5.4.21",` and Mongo Atlas, I can not seem to connect to my database in my node.js application

I tried to encode my connection string but that gives me `Invalid connection string`, if I remove `encodeURIComponent` I get authentication failed

```
mongoose.connect(encodeURIComponent("mongodb+srv://name:}Izu@[{!6o@cluster-oxzyp.mongodb.net/"), { dbName: "website", useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the username and password part of the connecting URI into the `options` section as shown below:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://cluster-oxzyp.mongodb.net", {
user: 'name',   //assuming this is your username
pass: '}Izu@[{!6o', //assuming this is your password
dbName: "website",
useNewUrlParser: true
```

});

This is probably happening due to the presence of `@` character in your password. Or you can try doing it like below:

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://name:${encodeURIComponent('}Izu@[{!6o')}@cluster-oxzyp.mongodb.net/`, {
user: '',
pass: '',
dbName: 'website',
useNewUrlParser: true });
```